# How to design a divide and conquer algorithm to checks if there is a pair ai,aj such that ai-aj= M in an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, divide-and-conquer

Given a list of integers a1,a2,...,an, write an algorithm that checks if there is a pair ai,aj such that ai-aj= M. The time complexity of the algorithm should be O(nlogn) or better. 
*As far as I am concerned, when the problem is ai+aj=M, this problem is very easy to solve. But I am in trouble now when the condition is ai- aj=M.*

Comment: if ai - aj = M then ai + aj = M + 2aj

Comment: Show what you've tried so far, how do you solve it for ai+aj=M ?

Comment: I am pleased that you mastered using your keyboard to type in your homework. Perhaps try writing some pseudo code

Comment: when the condition is ai+aj =M,the question is easy.Sort the list. Start from opposing ends. For example, see a[1] + a[n]:
If the sum is more than M, then certainly a[n] can’t be in the combination, so decrement right pointer.
 If the sum is less than M, then certainly a[1] can’t be in the combination, so increment left pointer.
 Meet somewhere in the middle

Comment: What have you tried for the subtraction ? If you find the addition pretty easy, it shouldn't be hard for you. We may help you finding it / explaining why it does not work but we won't just tell you the answer

Comment: Is my this idea correct?Sort the list. Start from opposing ends. When ai-aj=M, then aj +aj =M+2aj.Next, see a[1] + a[n]: If the sum is more than M+2a[n], then certainly a[n] can’t be in the combination, so decrement right pointer. If the sum is less than M+2a[n], then certainly a[1] can’t be in the combination, so increment left pointer. Meet somewhere in the middle.

Comment: this wouldn't work, a counter-example is easy to find. Have you tried binary search ?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using two divide and conquer algorithms.

First, sort the set using merge sort, which is O(logn).

Then, one-by-one, you can look at an element, ai, and see if M-ai, which will be aj, is an element.  Since the array is sorted, you can run a binary search, which is also a divide and conquer algorithm and runs in O(logn).  In the worst case, you will need to do this n times, once for every element in the list.

Therefore, the running time of this algorithm is O(logn + n*logn) = O(nlogn)